# How Do I Write Multiple Shapefiles to ASCII in R

Tags: loops, ascii

I have the attached code which works for converting a singe polygon into the ASCII format, however I have 27000 polygons so I need to be able to loop through them all. Currently this loop takes the same polygon and writes it 27084 times, overwriting the output each time.

What changes do I need to make in order for it to take each polygon within the directory and write as a distinct *.ascii file for each?

P.S The ascii files produced include '0.0000000' as the first value, any ideas on how to avoid this?

code

```
library("rgdal")
library("sp")
library("raster")
library("stringr")

wd<- "path//to//directory"
setwd(wd)

PatchShapes <- list.files(wd, pattern = "\\.shp$")  


asciiID<- paste0("", str_pad(1:27084, width = 2, side = "left", pad = 0), 
".ascii") #List to save each ASCII as 

## Raster to be used as extent templates
template<-raster("path//to//raster//file.txt") 

for (i in 1:27084){

p <- readOGR(dsn= wd , layer = "1") #Need to turn this "1" into i

pr<-raster()       

extent(pr)<-extent(template)  
template raster

res(pr)<-1000                

patch<-rasterize(x=p, y=pr ,field= p$Patch)  


writeRaster(patch, filename = "place//to//save//ASCII//file",   
format="ascii",overwrite=T, NAflag=0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would like something like this:

```
library("raster")
library("rgdal")

PatchShapes <- list.files(pattern = "\\.shp$")  

template <- raster("path//to//raster//file.asc") 
res(template)<-1000                

for (i in 1:length(PatchShapes)) {
    s <- shapefile(PatchShapes[i])
    f <- paste0(i, ".asc")
    patch <- rasterize(s, template ,field= s$Patch, filename=f, overwrite=TRUE, NAflag=0) 
}
```